# JHipster installation failure

Tags: node.js, jhipster

I am running the installation of JHipster:

npm install -g generator-jhipster

and got the following error:

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...^0.1.7","karma-ie-lau'

my system versions are:

npm -version ; 6.4.1
java -version ;  1.8.0_112
git --version ; 2.17.1.window.2
mvn -version ; 3.6.1

my log file is as below :

```
113 silly pacote version manifest for jhipster-core@6.0.5 fetched in 1565ms

114 silly resolveWithNewModule jhipster-core@6.0.5 checking installable status

115 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob 1979858ms

116 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for glob@7.1.3 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...04ddd01e","tarball":"'

117 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk 1979867ms

118 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for chalk@2.4.2 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...==","shasum":"3f73c2b'

119 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms

120 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 1984843ms

121 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...04ddd01e","tarball":"'

121 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

121 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)

121 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)

121 verbose stack     at <anonymous>

121 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)

122 verbose cwd C:\jhipster

123 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601

124 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "generator-jhipster"

125 verbose node v8.16.1

126 verbose npm  v6.4.1

127 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...04ddd01e","tarball":"'

128 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I really need some help or hints on how this can be handled.
Thank you and best regards,

Alvin

Comment: Something got probably corrupted in your global node_modules, try `npm cache clean --force` and re-install with `npm install -g generator-jhipster`. Beside that I see that you're using Windows 7, you should know that some things may not work on such old and unsupported version.

Comment: Thanks Gaei Marziou, I have done the npm cache clean --force before at home. But it got the same result. This morning, I did the same again but using faster internet connection. Fortunately, this time, it work properly. I suspect it is due to internet connection because at home, I use my cellphone tethering for connection, may be the internet connection not statbled. Now, It is installed and I have tried generating 1 application now. Thanks a lot.